# G510 FIBOCOM some at commands return ERROR in some commands

Tags: gsm, at-command

I use two FIBOCOM G510 GSM modems but one of them returns ERROR in some commands like:
`AT+CMGF=1\r`, `AT+CPIN=?` returns ERROR.
But some like `ATE0\r`, `AT+CLIP=1\r`, `AT+CBAUD?\r` returns OK.

I use baudrate 115200.
Q1:`ATE0\r`
R1:`\r\nOK\r\n`
Q2:`AT+CBAUD?\r`
R2:`\r\n+CBAUD: 115200\r\n\r\nOK\r\n`

Q3:`AT+CPIN=?`
R3:`\r\nERROR\r\n`
Q4:`AT+CMGF=1`
R4:`\r\nERROR\r\n`

Is there something I should set first or is it simcard issue or modem fault?

My other unit works good but I tested it 3 months ago and I think I would use some additional commands to prepare.
I am confuse what's its wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I checked sim card wiring for 3rd time and I found cardinal mistake. Socket was upside down and even wires was connected to the "right place" it did not comunicate.

After rewiring modem starts to work well.
Q5:`AT+CPIN?\r`
R5:`\r\n+CPIN: READY\r\n\r\nOK\r\n`